# converting string to jsonObject adding null value at the end of object

Tags: android, json

I have a json_string. while converting that string into `jsonObject` it is adding null at the end of string
my String is..

```
final String jsonStr=  "{\n" +
            "              \"prodCat_list\":[\n" +
            "                              {\n" +
            "                                  \"prods\":[\n" +
            "                                              {\n" +
            "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
            "                                              \"position\":\"1\",\n" +
            "                                              \"sku\":\"wwww345\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "                                              },\n" +
            "                                              {\n" +
            "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
            "                                              \"position\":\"2\",\n" +
            "                                              \"sku\":\"coof23\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "                                              },\n" +
            "                                              {\n" +
            "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
            "                                              \"position\":\"3\",\n" +
            "                                              \"sku\":\"dde45\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "                                              },\n" +
            "                                              {\n" +
            "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
            "                                              \"position\":\"4\",\n" +
            "                                              \"sku\":\"5555\"\n" +
            "                                               }\n" +
            "                                          ]\n" +
            "                               },\n" +
            "                             {\n" +
            "                                \"prods\":[\n" +
            "                                              {\n" +
            "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
            "                                              \"position\":\"1\",\n" +
            "                                              \"sku\":\"wwww345\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "                                              },\n" +
            "                                              {\n" +
            "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
            "                                              \"position\":\"2\",\n" +
            "                                              \"sku\":\"coof23\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "                                              },\n" +
            "                                              {\n" +
            "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
            "                                              \"position\":\"3\",\n" +
            "                                              \"sku\":\"dde45\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "                                              },\n" +
            "                                              {\n" +
            "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
            "                                              \"position\":\"4\",\n" +
            "                                              \"sku\":\"5555\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "                                              }\n" +
            "                                     ]\n" +
            "                              },\n" +
            "                ]\n" +
            "  }";
```

as i have two `jsonObject` with name `prods` in the `JSONArray` named `prodCat_list`, when i am converting this string to `JSONObject` like

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

this is converting it as below (Adding null at last)

```
{"prodCat_list":[{"prods": [{"sku":"wwww345","position":"1","cat_id":"9"},{"sku":"coof23","position":"2","cat_id":"9"},{"sku":"dde45","position":"3","cat_id":"9"},{"sku":"5555","position":"4","cat_id":"9"}]},{"prods":[{"sku":"wwww345","position":"1","cat_id":"9"},{"sku":"coof23","position":"2","cat_id":"9"},{"sku":"dde45","position":"3","cat_id":"9"},{"sku":"5555","position":"4","cat_id":"9"}]},null]}
```

Can someone tell me why this is adding null at last?

Comment: i think there's a comma exceeding. line before the squared parentesys

Comment: why don't you use json_encode() technique?

Comment: at third last line remove comma from  },\n" + as its the last element of array

Comment: Thanks Alberto Cappellina there was a comma exceeding.My Bad .

Comment: Yes Muhammad Hamza Shahid there was problem. thanks

Comment: What is json_encode() technique Pamur Can you please elaborate

Comment: how did you get the above data into string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    final String jsonStr=  "{\n" +
        "              \"prodCat_list\":[\n" +
        "                              {\n" +
        "                                  \"prods\":[\n" +
        "                                              {\n" +
        "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
        "                                              \"position\":\"1\",\n" +
        "                                              \"sku\":\"wwww345\"\n" +
        "\n" +
        "                                              },\n" +
        "                                              {\n" +
        "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
        "                                              \"position\":\"2\",\n" +
        "                                              \"sku\":\"coof23\"\n" +
        "\n" +
        "                                              },\n" +
        "                                              {\n" +
        "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
        "                                              \"position\":\"3\",\n" +
        "                                              \"sku\":\"dde45\"\n" +
        "\n" +
        "                                              },\n" +
        "                                              {\n" +
        "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
        "                                              \"position\":\"4\",\n" +
        "                                              \"sku\":\"5555\"\n" +
        "                                               }\n" +
        "                                          ]\n" +
        "                               },\n" +
        "                             {\n" +
        "                                \"prods\":[\n" +
        "                                              {\n" +
        "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
        "                                              \"position\":\"1\",\n" +
        "                                              \"sku\":\"wwww345\"\n" +
        "\n" +
        "                                              },\n" +
        "                                              {\n" +
        "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
        "                                              \"position\":\"2\",\n" +
        "                                              \"sku\":\"coof23\"\n" +
        "\n" +
        "                                              },\n" +
        "                                              {\n" +
        "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
        "                                              \"position\":\"3\",\n" +
        "                                              \"sku\":\"dde45\"\n" +
        "\n" +
        "                                              },\n" +
        "                                              {\n" +
        "                                              \"cat_id\":\"9\",\n" +
        "                                              \"position\":\"4\",\n" +
        "                                              \"sku\":\"5555\"\n" +
        "\n" +
        "                                              }\n" +
        "                                     ]\n" +
        "                              }\n" +
        "                ]\n" +
        "  }";



        JSONObject jsonObject= null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            Log.d("TAG","@@@ JSON :"+jsonObject.toString() );
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @user2025187  there was a comma exceeding line before the squared parentesys